# Scala containsSlice implementation

Tags: list, scala, slice

In scala containsSlice returns true if we've a sublist in a List with order maintained. Ex.

```
val sublst = List(1,2,3,4)
val lst = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
println(lst.containsSlice(sublst)) // true
```

Is there a way to write this logic without using this method?

Comment: How do you think this method was written ? Somebody wrote it. So, the existence of this method is undeniable proof that this method can be written.

Comment: True. And that is what i am looking for how it can be written using basic language constructs.

Comment: Its pretty simple actually. Describe how do you actually to check for a sublist without programming. Implement those exact steps in your program.

Answer (score 1):

If other library function can be used then this will work:

```
def containsSlice[T](list: List[T], slice: List[T]): Boolean = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: List[T]): Boolean =
    l.nonEmpty && (l.startsWith(slice) || loop(l.tail))

  slice.isEmpty || loop(list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def subList[A](sub: List[A], mainlist: List[A]): Boolean =
  if (mainlist.size < sub.size) false
  else if (sub == mainlist.take(sub.size)) true
  else subList(sub, mainlist.drop(1))
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest eliminating the `size` check, since it will traverse both lists.

Comment: That `take` is also creating a new `List` each time before comparing it and then throwing it away.